# Como calcular 2 inputs com virgula e aparecer em um terceiro input?

Tags: javascript

Tenho este script mas não funciona:

```
<input type="radio"  autocomplete="off" required value="Dinheiro e Cartão" name="pagamento" id="termos2"/> <span class="titulos_pgmnts">Dinheiro e Cartão</span><br>
                <div id="termoTexto2">
                <input type="text" id="soma1" value="<?php echo number_format($vtotal,2,",","."); // retorna: 270.78 ?>" name="">
                    <p></p>
                        <span class="titulos_pgmnts">Quanto em Dinheiro:</span> <input id="soma2" type="text" onKeyUp="mascaraMoeda(this, event)" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="off" value="" class="qtds_burgers" name="valortroco" placeholder="Digite o Valor" maxlength="6" onKeyPress="return(moeda(this,'.',',',event))"><p></p>
                    <p></p>
                        <span class="titulos_pgmnts">Restante no Cartão:</span> <input readonly id="result" type="text"  autocomplete="off" autocomplete="off"  class="qtds_burgers" name="valortroco" placeholder="0,00" maxlength="6" onKeyPress="return(moeda(this,'.',',',event))"><p></p>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <p></p>
    <script>
    //restantes entre cartão e dinheiro
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('input').on('keyup',function(){
    if(jQuery(this).attr('name') === 'result'){
    return false;
    }
  
    var soma1 = (jQuery('#soma1').val() == '' ? 0 : jQuery('#soma1').val());
    var soma2 = (jQuery('#soma2').val() == '' ? 0 : jQuery('#soma2').val());
    var result = (parseInt(soma1) - parseInt(soma2));
    jQuery('#result').val(result);
  });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: sua pergunta não está clara, coloque o html completo e mostre o que quer fazer

Comment: Ricardo editei lá

Comment: Ele está me retornando números inteiros eu queria calcular com virgulas ex.: 22,50 - 20,00 = 2,50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('input').on('keyup',function(){
    if(jQuery(this).attr('name') === 'result'){
    return false;
    }

    /* ####### troca virgula por ponto ############# */
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        var val = $(this).val().replace(',','.');
        $(this).val(val);
    });
    /* ############################################# */
    
    var soma1 = (jQuery('#soma1').val() == '' ? 0 : jQuery('#soma1').val());
    var soma2 = (jQuery('#soma2').val() == '' ? 0 : jQuery('#soma2').val());

    // use prseFloat 
    var result = (parseFloat(soma1) - parseFloat(soma2));

/* ########################## Solução com toLocaleString() ################# */  
//com R$
result = result.toLocaleString('pt-br',{style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'});

//sem R$
//result = result.toLocaleString('pt-br', {minimumFractionDigits: 2}); 
   /* ######################################################################### */ 
    
    jQuery('#result').val(result );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio"  autocomplete="off" required value="Dinheiro e Cartão" name="pagamento" id="termos2"/> <span class="titulos_pgmnts">Dinheiro e Cartão</span><br>
      <div id="termoTexto2">
          <input type="text" id="soma1" value="270.78" name="">
          <p></p>
          <span class="titulos_pgmnts">Quanto em Dinheiro:</span> <input id="soma2" type="text" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="off" value="" class="qtds_burgers" name="valortroco" placeholder="Digite o Valor" maxlength="6"><p></p>
          <p></p>
          <span class="titulos_pgmnts">Restante no Cartão:</span> <input readonly id="result" type="text"  autocomplete="off" autocomplete="off"  class="qtds_burgers" name="valortroco" placeholder="0,00" maxlength="6" onKeyPress="return(moeda(this,'.',',',event))"><p></p>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
     </div>
     <p></p>
```

Comment: Só uma dúvida tem como colocar ao digitar no Quanto em dinheiro ele aparecer com , está aparecendo com .

Comment: @Felipe, é possível sim mas vai dar zebra no input Restante no Cartão visto que a função dispara no keyup e ai só vai funcionar se digitar com ponto

Comment: Sem problema @Leo muito obrigado pela sua atenção!

Answer (score 0):

Para poder fazer este calculo é necessário primeiro fazer a substituição de ponto para virgula. Para que o número fique em um formato padrão o [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) que é o padrão internacional para representação de números binários em ponto flutuante.

Para isso devemos substituir ocorrências de vírgula (<kbd>,</kbd>) para ponto (<kbd>.</kbd>):

```
const soma1f = parseFloat(soma1.replace(/\s/g, "").replace(",", "."));
const soma2f = parseFloat(soma2.replace(/\s/g, "").replace(",", "."));
const result = soma1f - soma2f;
console.log(result);
```

Repare que não existe garantia que existirá apenas uma virgula, visto que o input é do tipo `text`.
Para mais informações como funciona o método `replace` segue a [documentação do MDN sobre string replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

- `\s` vai substituir os espaços em branco por string vazia `""`
- `\g` está dizendo que devemos substituir todas as ocorrências de maneira global.
- com o resultado desta transformação substituímos `vírgula` (<kbd>,</kbd>) por `ponto` (<kbd>.</kbd>)

Então é necessário tratar esses casos, afim de evitar que seja lançada uma exceção ao fazer o parseFloat.

Após calcular o resultado você deve mostrar os dados novamente utilizando a representação com `vírgula` novamente.

```
const resultstr = result.toString();
const resultstrcomvirgula = resultstr.replace(".",",")
```

Para colocar os valores de volta em sua variável devemos apenas substituir a variável `result` por `resultstrcomvirgula`.

```
jQuery('#result').val(resultstrcomvirgula);
```

Comment: Bem explicado porém como faço para implementar neste código que postei pois não manjo de javascript

Comment: Desculpa, não manjo de jQuery.